# Persian filename or chars in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, character-encoding

I want to read content of a .csv file whose name is in Persian (Farsi). Matlab seems not to be able to detect this file. I use this line of code:

```
a = csvread( <Persian filename> );
```

Comment: Two things. What character encoding are you using? Type `feature('DefaultCharacterSet')` in your command window. See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/how-the-matlab-process-uses-locale-settings.html) for more. And what does the file name look like if you type `ls` from the same directory (it will probably look a bit like gibberish, but you may be able to use that as a temporary workaround)?

Comment: the character encoding in use is "windows-1252". and as I am on windows, first when running dir I got some "?" in the place of the filename. then I changed system locale for non-unicode programs and now what I see is kind of gibberish with unfamiliar characters.

Comment: You can try changing your character set in Matlab. First note the default: `feature('DefaultCharacterSet')`. Then maybe try `feature('DefaultCharacterSet','ISO-8859-1')` or `feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF-8')` (each time you call this function it prints out the previous setting, not the one you're changing it to). Other than changing the file name to ASCII, this issue may be better answered by people at The MathWorks. You can try the [user forums](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/) or [file a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do).

Comment: You probably wanted those "?" symbols - that just indicates a character that cannot be displayed in the current font. In this case, the font used by the Matlab command window probably doesn't include Farsi characters. Changing the system locale may have confused things; the Matlab help indicates that on Windows the system and user locale need to be the same. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/setting-the-locale.html#brkh9v3-1.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a matter of getting the characters in to a Matlab string value through the command line and the editor. The Matlab GUI is implemented in Java, so it's using Unicode strings internally. Matlab `char` values are 16-bit Unicode. But when you save the M-file out, it may go out in the character encoding you have set in Matlab or your locale. And the font you're using in the Matlab GUI may not support the characters in the filename, so you may see "?" symbols or other placeholders at the command prompt even if the string value is internally correct.

The NTFS file system stores its file names in Unicode, so character encoding at the data level shouldn't be an issue in getting to the file itself. It'll just affect how the file's contents are interpreted.

If you just need to do this one time interactively, you could bypass the string-entering issue by using `uigetfile` to interactively select the file.

```
a = csvread( uigetfile() );
```

You can also get at it using the simple "8.3" filename that the Persian-named file has. At the Windows command prompt, use `dir /x` to see the short 8.3 filenames that correspond to the long file names. They'll be simple ASCII characters so you'll have no problem typing them in to the Matlab command window or editor. For example, I created a file named `تاده.txt`, and it has an 8.3 name of `6448~1.TXT`.

```
08/09/2013  01:10 AM    <DIR>                       .
08/09/2013  01:10 AM    <DIR>                       ..
08/09/2013  01:10 AM                 0 6448~1.TXT   ????.txt
```

As a test for programmatic access, just try pulling in all the file names in the directory with `f = dir();` (*not* `f = system('dir')`), looking to see which is the one you want, and then passing that to `csvread`, so none of the characters have to pass through the GUI text areas.